# Arrange rectangles in a spiral

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, tkinter, geometry, rectangles

I have a problem with arranging different recangles of different sizes spirally starting with the first rectangle in the middle (0/0). The anchor point of an rectangle is always in the top right corner. Here is a short pseudo code example of my current work. I have problems with the direction swap and the x-Axis correction during the upwards placement.

```
float x = 0;
float y = 0;

float width = 0;
float height = 0;

float nextWidth = 0;
float nextHeight = 0;

string next = "right";

for (int i = 0; i < rectangles.Length; i++)
{
    rectangles[i].Position = new Vector2(x,y);
    width = rectangles[i].Size.x;
    height = rectangles[i].Size.y;


    if (i < rectangles.Length - 1)
    {
        nextWidth = rectangles[i+1].Size.x;
        nextHeight = rectangles[i+1].Size.y;    
    }

    switch(next)
    {
        case "right":
            x += nextWidth;
            if (?)
            {
                next = "down";
            }

            break;

        case "down":
            x += nextWidth - width;
            y -= height;

            if (?)
            {
                next = "left";
            }

            break;

        case "left":
            x -= width;

            if (?)
            {
                next = "up";
            }

            break;

        case "up":
            //Still positioning problem with x-Axis
            y += nextHeight;

            if (?)
            {
                next = "right";
            }

            break;
    }
}
```

For a better understanding of my project I added a sketch:

[image]

I hope you understand what I try to do. Thanks for your help.

**EDIT:**
On the basis of the solution provided below by Reblochon Masque:

[image: City districts]

Comment: It is not clear - what should be with the third layer - will positions depend on 2nd laeyr rectangle size or they follow straight line?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by that question. Actually the positions of all recangles depend on the size of previous placed recangles. Could you maybe specify what you mean?

Comment: Will bottom line of the top of new spiral round be straight or with "stairs"?

Comment: The best way would be with "stairs" I guess to waste as little space as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a completely trivial problem to solve; the orientation of the rectangles changes wrt the position of their anchor point, and the side they are assigned to; you need to keep track of the boundaries as they move with the addition of each new rectangle, keeping in mind that there are two important boundaries to account for: the boundary for the current turn, and the boundary for the next turn.

Screenshots from the [GUI posted on github](https://github.com/ReblochonMasque/spiralofsquares):

> Showing anchor points, current and outer boundaries, and centers connected in sequence

[image]

> Showing the entire gui and around 900 rectangles.
>   *note: the left grey bar allows you to click and choose a rectangle size to add it to the spiral.*

[image]

> same as above, with current and outer boundaries, and centers connected in sequence, overlaid.

[image]

The proposed code is in python; there is a small GUI client attached to it, and a slightly better one posted on github. Maybe this will provide some measure of inspiration to complete your c# project.

```
"""
The coordinates at which a rectangle is anchored on canvas

"""


import random
import tkinter as tk

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 800, 800
CENTER = WIDTH // 2, HEIGHT // 2


class Anchor:
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Anchor(self.x + other[0], self.y + other[1])

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return Anchor(self.x - other[0], self.y - other[1])

    def __iter__(self):
        yield self.x
        yield self.y

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        a = (self.x, self.y)
        return a[idx]

    def get_mid(self, other):
        ox, oy = other[0], other[1]
        return Anchor((self.x + ox) // 2, (self.y + oy) // 2)

    def clone(self):
        return Anchor(self.x, self.y)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Anchor({self.x}, {self.y})'



"""
a Rectangle

"""

class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.bbox = None
        self.norm_bbox = None
        self.calc_bbox(Anchor())
        self.normalize_bbox()

    def calc_bbox(self, anchor):
        x, y = anchor
        self.bbox = [Anchor(anchor.x, anchor.y), (x + self.width, y + self.height)]
        self.normalize_bbox()

    def normalize_bbox(self):
        """
        set the anchor point to the top left corner of the bbox
        :return:
        """
        p0, p1 = self.bbox
        x0, y0 = p0
        x1, y1 = p1
        self.norm_bbox = [Anchor(min(x0, x1), min(y0, y1)), Anchor(max(x0, x1), max(y0, y1))]

    def get_center(self):
        tl, br = self.bbox
        return tl.get_mid(br)

    def __str__(self):
        res = f'Rectangle of width= {self.width}, height= {self.height}, bbox at: ' \
              f'{", ".join(str(elt) for elt in self.bbox)}'
        return res



"""
# Spiral Of Squares:

"""


class Spiral:
    """
    states:
    'right' --> add to the right side, going down
    'down'  --> add to the bottom side, going left
    'left'  --> add to the left side, going up
    'up'    --> add to the top side, going right

    """

    def __init__(self, anchor=CENTER, xoffset: int=5, yoffset: int=5):
        self.anchor = Anchor(*anchor)
        lr, td = self.anchor.x, self.anchor.y
        self.boundaries = {'right': lr, 'down': td, 'left': lr, 'up': td}
        self.current_x, self.current_y = self.anchor
        self.inner_boundaries = {'right': lr, 'down': td, 'left': lr, 'up': td}
        self.add_to = None
        self.xoffset = xoffset
        self.yoffset = yoffset
        self.rectangles = []
        self.anchor_points = [self.anchor.clone()]

    def add_rectangle(self, rect):
        self.rectangles.append(rect)
        if len(self.rectangles) == 1:
            self.place_first(rect)
        else:
            self.place(rect)
            self.calc_next_add_to_side()

    def place_first(self, rect):
        """
        places the first rectangle at current anchor
        updates the anchor
        """
        self.inner_boundaries = {'right': self.anchor.x + rect.width, 'down': self.anchor.y + rect.height,
                                 'left': self.anchor.x, 'up': self.anchor.y}
        self.boundaries = {k: v for k, v in self.inner_boundaries.items()}
        rect.calc_bbox(self.anchor.clone())
        self.anchor = self.anchor + (rect.width + self.xoffset, 0)
        self.add_to = 'right'
        self.anchor_points.append(self.anchor.clone())

    def place(self, rect):
        """
        places a rectangle at the current anchor, taking offsets and side into account,
        and minding the orientation of the rectangle wrt anchor point
        """
        w, h = rect.width, rect.height
        anchor = self.anchor.clone()

        if self.add_to == 'right':
            rect.calc_bbox(anchor)
            self.boundaries['right'] = max(self.boundaries['right'], self.inner_boundaries['right'] + w + self.xoffset)
            if self.boundaries['down'] < anchor.y + h:
                self.boundaries['down'] = anchor.y + h

        if self.add_to == 'down':
            anchor = anchor + (-w, 0)
            rect.calc_bbox(anchor)
            self.anchor = self.anchor + (-w, 0)
            self.boundaries['down'] = max(self.boundaries['down'], self.inner_boundaries['down'] + h + self.yoffset)
            if self.boundaries['left'] > self.anchor.x:  # -w already accounted for
                self.boundaries['left'] = self.anchor.x

        if self.add_to == 'left':
            anchor = anchor + (-w, -h)
            rect.calc_bbox(anchor)
            self.anchor = self.anchor + (-w, -h)
            self.boundaries['left'] = min(self.boundaries['left'], self.inner_boundaries['left'] - w - self.xoffset)
            if self.boundaries['up'] > self.anchor.y - h:
                self.boundaries['up'] = self.anchor.y

        if self.add_to == 'up':
            anchor = anchor + (0, -h)
            rect.calc_bbox(anchor)
            self.anchor = self.anchor + (w, -h)
            self.boundaries['up'] = min(self.boundaries['up'], self.inner_boundaries['up'] - h - self.yoffset)
            if self.boundaries['right'] < self.anchor.x + w:
                self.boundaries['right'] = self.anchor.x

    def calc_next_add_to_side(self):
        """
        calculates the next anchor position.
        cyclically updates the inner boundary for the next turn; this is out of phase
        so it doesn't affect the current turn.
        """

        w, h = self.rectangles[-1].width, self.rectangles[-1].height
        current_x, current_y = self.anchor

        if self.add_to == 'right':
            if current_y + h < self.inner_boundaries['down']:   # not overstep border
                current_x = self.inner_boundaries['right'] + self.xoffset
                current_y += h + self.yoffset
            else:                                               # oversteps -> change direction
                self.add_to = 'down'
                current_x += self.xoffset
                current_x = self.inner_boundaries['right']
                current_y = self.inner_boundaries['down'] + self.yoffset
            self.inner_boundaries['left'] = self.boundaries['left']

        elif self.add_to == 'down':
            if current_x > self.inner_boundaries['left']:
                current_x -= self.xoffset
            else:
                self.add_to = 'left'
                current_x = self.inner_boundaries['left'] - self.xoffset
                current_y = self.inner_boundaries['down']
            self.inner_boundaries['up'] = self.boundaries['up']

        elif self.add_to == 'left':
            if current_y > self.inner_boundaries['up']:
                current_x = self.inner_boundaries['left'] - self.xoffset
                current_y -= self.yoffset
            else:
                self.add_to = 'up'
                current_x = self.inner_boundaries['left']
                current_y = self.inner_boundaries['up'] - self.yoffset
            self.inner_boundaries['right'] = self.boundaries['right']

        elif self.add_to == 'up':
            if current_x < self.inner_boundaries['right']:
                current_x = current_x + self.xoffset
                current_y = self.inner_boundaries['up'] - self.yoffset
            else:
                self.add_to = 'right'
                current_x = self.inner_boundaries['right'] + self.xoffset
                current_y = self.inner_boundaries['up']
            self.inner_boundaries['down'] = self.boundaries['down']

        self.anchor = Anchor(current_x, current_y)
        self.anchor_points.append(self.anchor.clone())

    def get_current_boundaries(self):
        return self.inner_boundaries

    def get_boundaries(self):
        return self.boundaries

    def get_anchor_points(self):
        return self.anchor_points

    def get_center_points(self):
        center_points = []
        for rect in self.rectangles:
            center = rect.get_center()
            center_points.append(center)
        return center_points


if __name__ == '__main__':

    cr = 0
    if cr:
        num_rect = 18
    else:
        num_rect = 121
    rectangles = [Rectangle(random.randrange(30, 60), random.randrange(30, 60)) for _ in range(num_rect)]

    spiral = Spiral()
    for rect in rectangles:
        spiral.add_rectangle(rect)

    root = tk.Tk()
    canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT, bg='beige')
    canvas.pack(expand=True, fill='both')

    if cr:
        for idx, (rect, color) in enumerate(zip(spiral.rectangles, ['blue', 'red', 'green', 'black', 'cyan', 'grey', 'purple',\
                'lightgreen', 'lightblue', 'gold', 'black', 'blue', 'red', 'green', 'black', 'cyan', 'grey', 'purple'])):
            tl, br = rect.norm_bbox
            canvas.create_rectangle(*tl, *br, fill='white', outline=color, width=2)
            x, y = tl
            canvas.create_oval(x + 2, y + 2, x - 2, y - 1)
            print(*rect.get_center())
            canvas.create_text(*rect.get_center(), text=str(idx))
    else:
        for idx, rect in enumerate(spiral.rectangles):
            tl, br = rect.norm_bbox
            canvas.create_rectangle(*tl, *br, fill='white', outline='black', width=2)
            x, y = tl
            canvas.create_oval(x + 2, y + 2, x - 2, y - 1)
            print(*rect.get_center())
            canvas.create_text(*rect.get_center(), text=str(idx))

    root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot from the client provided:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed answer! I will try to take a closer look at it and implement it over the next week. This week I won't be able to do it yet.

Comment: Hey Reblochon Masque.
Thank you again for your answer. I was able to port your python code into C# and it worked out perferctly fine. The only problem between Python and my development area is that the coordinate systems are different which leads my program to arrange the rectangles the other way around the center (it goes  right -> up -> left -> down instead of right -> down -> left -> up). But this is fine and does not bother me at all. Greetings Joseph Gordan

Comment: I am glad to know that, thanks for your comment @JosephGordan